# retrieve data from ArrayList<Object> to Listview Android

Tags: android, listview

i have a problem with my ListView , I cannot get the data from an arraylist to listview . Data from arraylist was loaded successful from the data and when I put it in the ArrayAdapter the app always say ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
Here my code

EventList.java

```
public class EventList extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    DBHelper db;
    List<String> event_name;
    private TextView e_name,e_location,e_date,e_time,e_or;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_list);
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.eventlist);
        db.open();
        ArrayList<Event> elist= db.getEventlist();
        db.close();
        e_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.e_name);
        e_date=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.e_date);
        e_location =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.e_location);
        e_time =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.e_time);
        e_or =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.e_or);
      //  for(int i=0;i<elist.size();i++)
    //    {
     //       e_name.setText(elist.get(i).getEventName());
       //     e_date.setText(elist.get(i).getDate());
    //        e_location.setText(elist.get(i).getLocation());
      //      e_time.setText(elist.get(i).getTime());
        //    e_or.setText(elist.get(i).getOrganizer());

      //  }
        ArrayAdapter<Event> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Event>(
                this,
                R.layout.each_event,elist);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }

}
```

activity_event_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.greenwich.thaotb.eventmanagement.EventList">
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Event List"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Event"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Event"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/event_name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/bnt_search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_name"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/event_name"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/event_name" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eventlist"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bnt_search"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

each_event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/e_name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/e_location" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/e_date" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/e_time" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/e_or" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why is `findViewById(R.id.e_name);` inside the Activity? That will return null. You need to implement your own Adapter class.

Comment: i try to avoid using ArrayAdapter . Thanks you anyway i will comment that code too

Comment: But you *have to* use an ArrayAdapter. And you already are using an ArrayAdapter, so I am confused why you are trying to avoid it.

Comment: I try setText for all the TextView in each_item.xml and in my old code , the ArrayAdapter code was commented.

Comment: Check Anix's code! it will help you for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the the [constructor for ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) that you're using.  It says the resource ID must be a layout with a TextView.  It turns out, in this case, that the layout must contain ONLY a single TextView.  If you have a different case, use a different constructor.

ArrayAdapter populates a ListView by taking the toString() value of the object in its array, then putting that into the TextView identified by the layout you passed.

Comment: I believe it says it must be the resource ID to a layout file with a TextView since OP is using the two parameter constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I see it's a special case.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems

1. You can't use the `ArrayAdapter` constructor for displaying any complex data objects. It will just `toString` all the objects.
2. Calling `findViewById(R.id.e_name)` (and the others) from within the Activity will return `null` because `@+id/e_name` isn't from the `activity_event_list.xml` file.

To solve these, you'll need to [implement a custom ArrayAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) for your Event objects.

Something like so

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {
    public EventAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> events) {
       super(context, 0, events);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position
       Event event = getItem(position);    
       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.each_event, parent, false);
       }

       TextView eName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.e_name);
       // get other views ...

       eName.setText(event.getEventName());
       // set other views...

       return convertView;
   }
}
```

Then in the Activity, you can do

```
ArrayList<Event> elist= db.getEventlist();
EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, elist);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read your code, and I think it's worth first checking how `ListViews` and and `Adapters` work together. Here's a great [article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) I think you should take a look at.

## Solution

You can achieve what you want by

- Creating a custom class that represents an event, it should be something like this

  ```
  class Event{
      private String mName;
      private String mLocation;
      private String mDate;
      //you get the idea ...
      public Event (String name, String location, String date){
          mName = name;
          mLocation = location;
          mDate = date;
      }
      //some getters
      public String getName (){
          return mName;
      }
      public String getLocation (){
          return mLocation;
      }
      public String getDate (){
          return mDate;
      }
      //you can add other logic here depending on what you want your event to do
  }
  ```
- Creating you collection of `Events`, a `List<Event>` will do
- Creating your custom `EventAdapter`, I would recommend to extend the `BaseAdapter` class (any other Adapter class would do)

### A tutorial might help you more

[Here is](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/) a great step by step tutorial showing how to implement what I have mentioned above.

Comment: Just curious, why `BaseAdapter`? If you are going to use a `List` anyways, then `ArrayAdapter` is preferred.

Comment: I have class event and I forgot to post it . Thanks anyway